# Which Package or assembly had ISession?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cqrs, event-sourcing

I used this series to work on CQRS/ES with ASP.NET:

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/real-world-cqrs-es-with-asp-net-and-redis-part-2-the-write-model/

My problem is somewhere in the code it uses ISession,that I don't know what assembly/package has it. Bases on document I need to install CQRSLite but when I try to install it I get an error.

```
private readonly ISession _session;
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Could not install package 'CqrsLite 0.12.9'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I am using Visual studio 2015 and .net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a smarter way, but I right-click on the class name in the editor and select "Go to definition."

It disassembles the class and at the top shows the name of the assembly and where it's referenced. If it's a Nuget package that's going to give you the name of the package.

```
#region Assembly EPPlus, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1
// C:\.. etc... etc...\packages\EPPlus.4.1.0\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#endregion
```

Comment: this was works it the reference exists in the project, I am writing it and it is not reference anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

I need to change the version of the project to NETFramework 4.6.1 and install CQRSLite package.